# count distinct and average them based on 2 other column

Tags: postgresql

I am not sure how to word this, please allow me to explain. From this table

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id int4 NULL,
    shot varchar NULL,
    layer varchar NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (id,shot,layer) VALUES 
(1,'10','a')
,(1,'10','a')
,(1,'10','b')
,(1,'10','c')
,(1,'20','a')
,(2,'10','a')
,(2,'10','a')
,(2,'10','a')
,(2,'10','a')
,(2,'10','b')
,(2,'10','b')
,(2,'20','a');
```

How can I query the average layer of each shot and display them per ID?

For example id 1 has 2 shots, one with 3 layers and another with 1 layer so the average would be 2 layer per shot.

Id 2 has 2 shots which average out at 1.5 layer per shot.

```
id  |  average layer
____________________
1   |  2
2   |  1.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to count the distinct number of shots per layer and id (if I have understood you properly) in a sub-query then average over that

```
select id, avg(layers_per_shot) as average
from (
  select id, shot, count( distinct layer) as layers_per_shot
  from test
  group by id, shot ) Q
group by id
```

[Working fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4KBta5FZccQcpJpzeGBrT4/0) and results from it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. I've tried the sub query alone, but it didn't seem to do what I wanted it to do. The result only showed 3 rows and the average didn't look correct.

Comment: Sub-query alone won't - the sub-query gives you a list of ids and shots with a layer per id and shot.  Full query to get the average.  Will add link and results - it gives the answers you asked for

Comment: That is interesting. I'm getting different result on Dbeaver. I'll try on something different. Thank you!